# VS2013 integration with Intel Fortran Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, fortran, intel-fortran

I have several C++ codes I develop in VS2013 Professional. Today, I installed the Intel Fortan Compiler (Composer XE2013 SP1), and now none of my C++ Projects will load. When I open my solution, I see:

myprojectname (load failed)

```
The Project requires user input. Reload the project for more information
```

If I reload the project, I get a popup error that reads:

```
Parameter "path" cannot be null.
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this without just reinstalling VS? 
Thanks!

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

A Google search on this error message tends to suggest that you may get this if the project is on a network drive. The recommended solution is to right click on the project (in Solution Explorer), select Reload Project, and respond to the prompts.